# ConEmu with Git Bash - Show folder in tab bar

Tags: git-bash, conemu

I'm usually running Git Bash in ConEmu tabs.  It would be really handy to show the name of the current directory in the tab bar for each instance of Git Bash, but if I set the tab template to `%d` or `%f`, I always get my Windows home directory, no matter where I `cd` to in Git Bash.

Is there a way to display the path in the tab bar?  As you can see from the attached screenshot, I'm navigated to the `banana` folder, but `ccook` (my home dir) is shown in the tab.

The Title (`%s`) seems to contain the full path, but that's too long for my tabs.

[image: Incorrect folder name in tab bar with %f]

The best I'm currently able to achieve is to use `%s` and add `MINGW64` as a Skipped word from title, but that still gets me the full path instead of just the current folder.  If there was a way to specify a regex I could exclude everything but the text after the final `/`.

Comment: RTFM https://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html

Comment: Ah, that's got it, thanks - I hadn't found that page.  Bit harsh on me, though.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you do it.  I'm reading the documentation and it's still not clear.

Answer (score 2):

For Cygwin users, add `PROMPT_COMMAND='ConEmuC -StoreCWD'` to the .bashrc.

Per suggestion from @Jeffrey-Harmon

```
if [[ -n "${ConEmuPID}" ]]; then 
        PROMPT_COMMAND='ConEmuC -StoreCWD' 
fi
```

edit:

Looking at the documentation page, this suggestion is there as well now.

https://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html#bash_and_other_cygwin_shells

Comment: This worked with Git Bash as well, but you should wrap this in an if statement, so if you ever open the shell outside of ConEmu, it won't display an error after every command about not being able to find ConEmuC.

    if [[ -n "${ConEmuPID}" ]]; then
      PROMPT_COMMAND='ConEmuC -StoreCWD'
    fi